# Hold Key Doesn't Repeat in Every Application in WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I am using Dell XPS13 9360 running Windows 10 with everything up to date (Windows update, Dell update, Bios, Intel Chipset, etc).

Recently, possibly after last bios upgrade, holding keys no longer repeat properly in every applications. A few examples:

- Office 2016 - backspace repeats but arrow and delete keys don't
- Chrome/IE11 - nothing repeats
- Edge - all keys repeat as expected

I tried all the suggestions around ticking or unticking "User Filter Keys" option. It didn't solve the problem. On-screen keyboard has the same behavior

The only way to "fix" the issue is to uninstall all keyboard drivers in device manager and reboot following the prompt. Once the PC is back up, every key repeats normal, but only till the next reboot where the issue reoccurs.

Is there anything else I can try to solve the problem once for all?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use On-Screen keyboard to see if the issue still occur in Office/Edge.

Update the keyboard drivers.

Use other keyboard to see if the issue still occur.

Boot PC in a clean environment. Here is link：How to perform a clean boot in Windows:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

After numerous tests, I found the root cause. It was because of a security token I installed. As part of the security protocol, it installed certain precaution module around the keyboard driver. It kind of hijacked the keyboard in a way it considers "secure".

However, I wasn't able to uninstall the token cleanly. So I ended up re-installing Windows 10 with the option of keeping all my personal files. After the re-installation, keyboard was working normally.